# "The formula refers to a column that does not exist. Check the formula for spelling mistakes or change the non-existing column to an existing column."

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, csom, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to create calculated column using csom.

```
var fieldXml="<Field Name='calctest' DisplayName='calctest' StaticName='calctest' Type='Calculated' Required='FALSE' ColName='sql_variant1' Format='DateOnly' EnforceUniqueValues='FALSE' Description='weg' Indexed='FALSE' ResultType='DateTime' ReadOnly='TRUE' LCID='1033' Version='2' ><Formula>=DATE(YEAR(Approval_x0020_Date)+3,MONTH(Approval_x0020_Date)+1,DAY(Approval_x0020_Date)+5)</Formula><FormulaDisplayNames>=DATE(YEAR([Approval Date])+3,MONTH([Approval Date])+1,DAY([Approval Date])+5)</FormulaDisplayNames><FieldRefs><FieldRef Name="Approval_x0020_Date" /></FieldRefs></Field>";
olist.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(fieldXml, true, AddFieldOptions.AddToDefaultContentType);
fieldTxt.Update();
olist.Update();
clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();
```

After executing i am getting Error:

> The formula refers to a column that does not exist. Check the formula for spelling mistakes or change the non-existing column to an existing column.

when i am running same code just changing column in formula, it runs smoothly and creates calculated column perfectly.

i.e If i Use Column name=Approval Date (Static name="Approval_x0020_Date"), it will throw above error.

If I use Column name=ApprovalDate (Static name="ApprovalDate"), it will work fine.

Does anyone know why it is not accepting 2 or more than 2 words of column name.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i got solution.

I replaced [Approval_x0020_Date] with [Approval Date].
i.e with display name.

Thanks Submits

Comment: Strange! In my case I have to use the internal name, after having tried display name. We love SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the column name in square brackets like `[Approval_x0020_Date]`.

The name should be the internal name of the column.

Comment: Tried. not working, it gives same error

Answer (score 0):

I replicated this issue :

1. I created site column
2. Added the site column to a list
3. Created a Calculated field, as site column
4. It'll tell me the column doesnt exist

Solution :

1. Create a column inside the list instead